# Import data with feeds that is not in the source file

Tags: feeds

I need support to set a field on a feeds mapping that is not in the source.

I already have some code that for some reason is not working.

If I use **hook_feeds_after_parse**, I can set the value but I need to use the method below (new mapping).

```
function  MYMODULE_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
    $items['TEST IMPORT'] = array(
        'description' => 'TEST IMPORT',
        'rule' => '1 * 1 * *',
        'callback' => ' MYMODULE_testImport',
    );

    return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_testImport() {
    $test_field_value = 'this is a test';
    $feeds_importer = 'test_feeds';
    $feeds_source = feeds_source($feeds_importer);
    $field_mappings = $feeds_source->importer->processor->getMappings();

    $path_to_xml = 'http://.../sites/default/files/test_content.xml';

    foreach ($field_mappings as &$mapping) {
        if ($mapping['target'] == 'field_test_field') {
            $mapping['test_field'] = $test_field_value;
        }
    }

    $feeds_source->importer->processor->addConfig(array('mappings' => $field_mappings)); 

    drupal_static_reset('FeedsProcessor::getMappings');

    $feeds_config = $feeds_source->getConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher);

    $feeds_config['source'] = $path_to_xml;

    $config = array(
        'process_in_background' => TRUE,
    );

    $feeds_source->setConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher, $feeds_config);
    $feeds_source->importer->addConfig($config);
    $feeds_source->save();
    $feeds_source->startImport();

    while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $feeds_source->import());
}

function MYMODULE_feeds_processor_targets_alter(array &$targets, $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type == 'node' && $bundle == 'test_content') {
    if (isset($targets['field_test_field'])) {
      $targets['field_test_field']['callback'] = 'MYMODULE_set_test_field';
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_set_test_field(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $target, array $values, array $mapping) {
    if ($source->importer->id == 'test_feeds') {
        if (!empty($mapping['test_field'])) {
            $entity->{$target}[$entity->language][0]['value'] = $mapping['test_field'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the importer's machine name from the source, instead of doing `$source->id`, this should be `$source->importer->id`.
2. I don't know what you are trying to do with `$mapping['_ad_area']` exactly. `$mapping` contains target configuration (aka mapping settings). I don't see `form_callbacks` on your target code. The default taxonomy reference field also doesn't have an option called '_ad_area'. If you added mapping for the 'field_ad_area' target, values coming from the source should exist in `$values`.
3. You say you want to provide a value that is not in your original source. If this is a fixed value, you can use the Tamper plugin "Set default value" from the [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module. If you are using the CSV parser, on the mapping form you can just enter a source column name that does not exist in your CSV file. Otherwise, select "Blank source".

   If you programmatically want to set a value, you can implement the hook `hook_feeds_after_parse()` in a custom module:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_after_parse().
 */
function mymodule_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
  if ($source->importer->id != 'qc_data_generic_import') {
    return;
  }

  foreach ($result->items as &$item) {
    $item['Blank source 1'] = 'My value';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I think the hook_feeds_after_parse() doesn't help in my case because I'm getting the values I want to add to the blank sources in another place. To be easier and more complete, I've created a new test content type and feeds especifically for the case I need. The complete code is here: http://dpaste.com/3A78Z2M. On line 13, I define the variable and the value that I want to insert in my node. The content type machine name is "test_content" and has a title field and the "field_test_field".

Comment: Forgot to say that the value(s) I want to add are not fixed, in my above example, it's fixed but in my (more complex code) I'm getting those values from another source. Basically, I define them in the function "MYMODULE_testImport"

Comment: I also tried your solution using hook_feeds_after_parse() and it doesn't set the values, also

Comment: You can also implement a custom source with the hook `hook_feeds_parser_sources_alter()`. This hook is invented to be able to add in values from other sources. See feeds.api.php.
Not sure if this is helpful in your case as you said implementing `hook_feeds_after_parse()` didn't work for you.

Comment: I already tried with hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter (as you can see in the code attached) and still doesn't work. Maybe I have something wrong in the MYMODULE_testImport function that makes all the hooks I tried, to not work?

Comment: Can someone give me a working example? At this moment I don't know if there's something else that is causing all the examples given to not work. Tried everything without success.